# DatePicker for MVC5, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, datepicker

I am trying to add a DatePicker to my Edit and Create Views in MVC5.  I have followed a few tutorials online.  One was JavaScript and the other was Bootstrap.  Either way, I am finding errors and I get stumped.

Let's work with Bootstrap, since I already removed all the code from the js tutorial.  Here is where I am at:

I installed the BootStrap.Datepicker with NuGet

In my model, my date fields look like this:

```
     [Key]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Transaction Date")]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "date")]

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Disposition Date")]
    public DateTime? DISPOSITION_DT { get; set; }
```

I added the following to my BundleConfig.cs

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datePicker").Include(
       "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
       "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datepicker").Include(
                 "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"));
```

Added the following to my _Layout.cshtml

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/datepicker")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datePicker")
```

This is a sample of my edit view, where we have a date field

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DISPOSITION_DT, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DISPOSITION_DT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DISPOSITION_DT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my script at the bottom of my view

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'lll'
    });
});
```

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

}

When the view loads, I get the following error . . .

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datetimepicker'

My research tells me that this is probably due to my js files not loading properly.  But, I don't understand why or how to resolve it.

Thank you for your help.  Please keep in mind that I am new to MVC5 and Bootstrap and C#. I previously coded in asp.net web forms, vb.net . .  and used ajax tools to quickly add my date pickers in the past.  My job is moving in a new direction and I am an old dog trying to learn a new trick.

Comment: Are the scripts in your bundle getting added to the html above or below the `<script>` tag in your view?

Comment: @gunr2171   I was following a tutorial which stated to add the scripts at the bottom of the View.  After reading your comment, I tried moving the script to above to the top of the view - but the error remains.   Thanks.

Comment: Can you view the source of the generate page and paste which `js` are included.

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question . . . .

The tutorial I was following had a typo in the bundle

It was not "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

It was:                   bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

Problem Solved.  The datepicker is working now.